# Grails: How do you call a tagLib inside a GSP expression?

Tags: grails, grails-2.0, gsp, taglib

So I have this tagLib;

```
def trimTo = { attrs, body ->
    int length = attrs.int('length')
    String text = body()
    if (text.size() > length) {
        text = text.substring(0, length - 1) + '...'
    }
    out << text
}
```

Normally I'm using it like this;

```
<g:trimTo length="50">${fieldValue(bean: fooInstance, field: "textEng")}</g:trimTo>
```

And all is good.

But I want to call it in a g:select tag that looks like;

```
<g:select name="phrases" from="${Foo.list()}" optionValue="${{it.textEng}}" multiple="multiple" optionKey="id" size="25" value="${fooParentInstance?.children*.id}" class="many-to-many"/>
```

Specifically I would like to use it to shorten what is being displayed by the optionValue attribute, the results of {it.textEng}.

I have tried several different combinations can can't seem figure out the correct syntax.

Thanks in advance for any assistance.

*edited for spelling

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Managed to figure it, mostly through trial and error with a tiny bit of reading and reasoning tossed in for good measure.

```
optionValue="${{g.trimTo([length: 50], it.textEng)}}"
```

Thanks all,